# Confusion on covariance matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, covariance, principal-component-analysis

I have read from wikipedia that the equation of Covariance matrix is as follows:

$$\Sigma_{i j}=\operatorname{cov}\left(X_{i}, X_{j}\right)=\mathrm{E}\left[\left(X_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\left(X_{j}-\mu_{j}\right)\right]$$

But while reading the steps of PCA in various links and MATLAB codes etc, I encountered the covariance matrix again, but no expectation was found, like shown below (for eg. [here](http://web.missouri.edu/%7Ehantx/ECE8001/notes/PCA_Compute.pdf)):

$$\mathbf{A = (x_1 \space x_2 \space  x_3 \dots x_N)}$$

and covariance matrix as $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$

How does the both matrices come equal? I am lost here. Please clarify my doubt.

**UPDATE :** OK when I thought again I can see here a link between correlation concept (from the covariance matrix) and dot product concept (in the matrix multiplication case). I know that correlation and inner product has some similarities. As far as I know correlation applies for random vectors and inner product for deterministic vectors. Please correct me if I am wrong? Even if what I told is correct, I am not satisfied. :(

Comment: Do you know these relations :

$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X,X) = \mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{E}(X^{2}) - \mathrm{E}(X)^{2} $$

and 

$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm{E}(XY) - \mathrm{E}(X)\mathrm{E}(Y) $$ ?

Comment: Assume the $x_i's$ are centered and divide the $C$ matrix by $N$ and look at the $i-j$th term. Then, you see that the $ij$-th entry of $C$ is the empirical estimate of the $ij$-th entry of $\Sigma_{ij}$.